# Linux TCP stack packet injection

Tags: tcp, stack

Could i inject packets to Linux TCP stack without modifying the ethernet driver? Could i do this with using a library or sth ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'inject packets to Linux TCP stack' you mean send some data that the Linux kernel will treat as a frame coming from an Ethernet interface then you can use a 'tap' device. If an IP packet (layer 3) is good enough, then use a 'tun' device.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP

http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/marcelo/linux-2.4/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt

Comment: Yes i mean send packets from same computer that the packets are like coming from ethernet device.
I am searching for a solution that i can embed to my C++ code. If i create a network tap, how could i send packets to the OS that my application runs on?

Comment: Just open /dev/net/tun, configure it and write your packets there... See the other link added to my answer (already linked in the Wikipedia article).

Answer (score 1):

[Libnet](http://libnet.sourceforge.net/)

> Libnet is a generic networking API that provides access to several protocols. It is not designed as a 'all in one' solution to networking. Currently many features that are common in some network protocols are not available with Libnet, such as streaming via TCP/IP. We feel that Libnet should not provide specific features that are possible in other protocols. If we restrict Libnet to the minimal needed to communicate (datagram/packets) then this allows it to support more interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, if you're just wondering about injecting hand-crafted packets into the network, read the man pages and look for online help with raw sockets.  Some good places to start are man 7 raw, man packet, and there are some ok tutorials at security-freak.net, though the code there is not written particularly well for my tastes.